# Unable to reset mysql password on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried various things but i am unable to reset my root password of mysql workbench.I have installed mysql on my machine but it is asking me for password .But when I type the default password root it is not working ..I have seen various links but none of them very helpful can anyone tell me how to do it? When I try this command

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

It gives me

```
160706 10:16:20 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
160706 10:16:20 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
160706 10:16:20 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

 sudo killall -9 mysqld

And when i fire sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &

I get different error


160706 10:22:22 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160706 10:22:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 8487 ...
```

Comment: with the limited info you gave us, yikes

Comment: okay let me update my question

Comment: "My password isn't working" is not a question, and it's not programming related.

Comment: Please google "MySQL skip password". Maybe you will get a Chance to change it then

Comment: i have installed mysql and it not taking the default password so my question is how to reset password

Comment: the daemon is already running. You are attempting v2 to bind to port 3306 and it says no way Jose. Good news for you unlike many others .... at least you have mysqld_safe

Comment: i google mysql skip password but i got an error

Comment: @Drew- how to resolve it ?

Comment: for your o/s, stop your mysqld

Comment: i did it but getting different error please see i have updated my question

Comment: what error. Looks fine at the bottom. I honestly don't do these types of questions anymore. They take an hour each time.

Comment: There was a warning has been logged while you attempted to start mysql daemon. That is fine and you can ignore as for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access for the ubuntu, then kill the mysqld process ungracefully. Also make sure you dont do any transaction while doing this which could leads to data corruption.

> sudo kill -9